# Finding the solutions of a complicated equation

Tags: python, equation, solver

I have a function `(x^x)*((1-x)^(1-x))*(k^(x/2)) = 1` which has a `unique solution` in `0 < x < 1` for a given natural number `k`.

Can I use Python to find these solutions, or is my equation too complicated?

Comment: Yes, of course, you can.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Find root of a transcendental equation with python](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43047463/find-root-of-a-transcendental-equation-with-python)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can use Python to solve this equation.

I suggest you fix k=2 to simplify. Wolfram Alpha can verify your results: https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=(x%5Ex)*((1-x)%5E(1-x))*(2%5E(x%2F2))+%3D+1

Depending on how you do your root search, you may have to take a first derivative with respect to x and place that into Python, as well.

Comment: I would like to find the solution for every k from 2 to 100. Can Numpy do this? I really know almost nothing about programming, so I'm not too sure

Comment: Yes, you can solve this using Numpy.  Can you look at Chris Mueller's  answer at http://stackoverflow.com/a/43048035/509840 ? You would switch out Chris's opt_fun with your own.

Comment: It didn't work. I got the error "numpy.ndarray object is not callable" when I changed nothing in his code except the function.